# MSMQ missing from Server Manger after patching

Tags: msmq

We have MSMQ installed on a Windows 2008 R2 installation. Recently, MSMQ disappears from Server Manager after each patching run.
Server manager console cannot show the MSMQ branch that is supposed to be under Features.

The MSMQ service is still running in the background but hangs when we attempt to restart it or shut it down.
I have had to manually kill mqsvc.exe to get anywhere.

I can still see queue definitions in C:\Windows\System32\msmq\storage\lqs and the domain accounts accessing the box have admin rights.

We have had to reinstall MSMQ and recreate the queues after each monthly patching run. 
I was wondering if anyone has experienced such a problem and I am interested in how you solved the issue.

Comment: Are you just applying Windows Updates or policy updates as well?

Comment: Hi John. After more investigations, discovered that the queue branch actually disappears after a reboot. Our infrastructure team also confirmed that only Windows updates went in this time.

Comment: Is the update the only time the server is rebooted in a month - the problem doesn't appear if you reboot now, for example?
Backup the LQS folder so you don't have to manually recreate the queues each time.

Comment: We tried a reboot and were able to replicate the problem. We did back up the LQS folder the last time it happened and only had to reconfigure MSMQ.

Comment: Errors in event log from MSMQ trying to start up? Is MSMQ AD-integrated?

Comment: Hi John, this is what the event log recorded: "The Message Queuing service cannot start because a queue is in an inconsistent state."

Comment: Are you using public queues at all? If so, do any of them get deleted on a regular basic? (Looking at KB 827493)

Comment: No, we do not have public queues in use.

Comment: Can you give the registry value (PurgeInconsistentQueues) in the KB article a try? Obviously this makes MSMQ purge messages from queues that are in an inconsistent state but I don't know if that actually impacts you.
Probably an easier test is to stop MSMQ automatically starting up after a reboot and check the machine can see an AD domain controller before manually starting it. Could be a timing issue where MSMQ cannot contact a DC quickly enough.